# ListView.setSelection(int) not selecting item

Tags: android, listview

It's a common question, I know.

I have a `ListView` of 100 items having `0` to `99` positions. Only first 10 items are visible when the list is rendered for the first time, right? I can use `setSelection(int)` in `ListView.post(Runnable)` for positions `0` to `9`, that's working correctly. What if I want to select an item having position `45`? `setSelection(int)` doesn't seem to work because when the list is rendered we do not have any item having position `45` rather it will be rendered when we scroll down. So my question is:

How can I select an item (and make it visible) even the item is not rendered?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
  listview.post(new Runnable() 
   {
    @Override
    public void run() 
      {
        listview.setSelection(45);   // your position
        View view = listview.getChildAt(45);
        if (view != null) 
        {
            view.requestFocus();   //request focus on row
        }
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: `view.requestFocus();` returns false. Not selecting item

Comment: do u have 45 items in your list?

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I have more than 45 items in my list (mentioned 100 in my question).